# Help with jQuery show/hide on keyup

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a text box and when I type characters into the box it hides rows in my table that don't contain the text. How can I reform the following code so that it re-evaluates the function so that it starts showing the rows again when I press backspace?

This is as far as I got:

```
$("#txtFilter").keyup(function () {
                var text = $("#txtFilter").val();
                if () {
                    $(".tableStripe .tdName:not(:contains(" + text + "))").closest("tr").show();
                }
                else { 
                    $(".tableStripe .tdName:not(:contains(" + text + "))").closest("tr").hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `event` var to your callback function, then specify the keycode for backspace:

```
$("#txtFilter").keyup(function(event) {
    var text = $("#txtFilter").val();
    if (event.keyCode == 8) { // 8 = keycode for backspace
        $(".tableStripe .tdName:not(:contains(" + text + "))").closest("tr").show();
    } else { 
        $(".tableStripe .tdName:not(:contains(" + text + "))").closest("tr").hide();
    }
});
```

For more javascript keycodes, do a google search for 'javascript keycodes'

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 8) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$("#txtFilter").keyup(function () {
      $(".tableStripe tr").hide();
      setTimeout(function(){
            var text = $("#txtFilter").val();                                
            $(".tableStripe .tdName:not(:contains(" + text + "))").closest("tr").show();
      },10);
});
```